# CloudWatch EC2 - Finding EC2 Server's Instance ID and Instance Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a custom CloudWatch metric that I am reporting. My call looks like:

```
$dimensions = array(
    array(
        "Name" => "InstanceId",
        "Value" => "need instance id here"
    ),
    array(
        "Name" => "InstanceName",
        "Value" => "need instance name here"
    )
);

// API call to save cpu usage
$client->putMetricData(array(
    "Namespace" => "mynamespace",
    "MetricData" => array(
        array(
            "MetricName" => "CPU_Usage",
            "Value" => $cpu_usage,
            "Unit" => "Percent",
            "Timestamp" => time(),
            "Dimensions" => $dimensions
        )
    )
));
```

I want to populate InstanceId and InstanceName with values corresponding to the server running the script.

Is there a way to do this through CloudWatch API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used an internal IP call to get the instance ID, and with that ID called EC2's `describeTags` method to get the instance name.

```
$instance_id = $curl->get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id");
$tags_result = $ec2_client->describeTags(array(
    "Filters" => array(
        array(
            "Name" => "resource-id",
            "Values" => array(
                $instance_id
            )
        ),
        array(
            "Name" => "key",
            "Values" => array(
                "Name"
            )
        )
    )
));
$instance_name = $tags_result["Tags"][0]["Value"];
```